# autocomplete extender shows only small portion within grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use a autocomplete Extender Within grid.This extender works well.
 
But the problem here is we cant see all values inside extender.only small portion is displayed to the user.
can we completely view extender values by adjusting grid height ?

pls help me to solve this.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: You can do so by playing around with css

Comment: can you pls help me to solve this in css..

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I am not sure what properties  you are setting on extender currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your extender flyout styling as follows in your aspx file

```
 <style>
        /*AutoComplete flyout */

        .autocomplete_completionListElement
        {
            overflow: auto; /* Set multiple other properties to meet your needs */
            height: 200px; /*Adjust the height as per your needs*/

        }
    </style>
```